# Grub Rescue No Windows Repair Disk Plz Help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I Thought that deleting the partition with Ubuntu on it, it would uninstall it I know now that it doesn't. But now I cant open windows because all I get when I boot is the grub rescue screen I don't know how to boot from a USB (Where I downloaded Ubuntu From) and I don't have the disk to install windows 7 because it came with the PC anything will help. Thank You in advance. I'll be able to give feedback on weekdays.